# Need to output a function That takes in strings and ints in python

Tags: python, string, formatting, format, concatenation

The function in question is:

```
switch({source}, condition1, Condition Nth, value1, value Nth)
```

The Way I need to output it involves using 0 and 1s (True/False) and will look like this:

```
"switch([.]ALARM,1,0,On,Off, Unknown)"
```

Where the 1 and 0 need to be ints instead of strings.

The program we have to use at work does not allow me to use .format and I was curious is there a way to make this happen.

Example of what I have tried:

##### First test (index 0 is the 0 and/or 1s in question for both variables):

```
formula = "switch({source}, \"" + int(conditionOne[0]) + "\""+  "," + "\"" + int(conditionTwo[0]) + "\""+ "," + "\"" + conditionOne[1] + "\"" + "," + "\"" + conditionTwo[1] + "\"" + ", \"Unknown\")"
```

##### Second test (the program reads {} as sets instead of formatting:

```
    test = "switch({source}, \"" + {0} + "\""+  "," + "\"" + {1} + "\""+ "," + "\"" + conditionOne[1] + "\"" + "," + "\"" + conditionTwo[1] + "\"" + ", \"Unknown\")".format(conditionOne[0],conditionTwo[0])
```

## Edit and Answer:

I reached out to ignition personal and found out they use %d, which I have never used since the updates of python 3. I am guessing that program uses an old form of python?

Here is the code that gets it to work, if anyone else out there uses the ignition program:

```
test3 =   "switch({source}, %d, %d," % (int(conditionOne[0]),int(conditionTwo[0])) + "\"" + conditionOne[1] + "\"" + "," + "\"" + conditionTwo[1] + "\"" + ", \"Unknown\")"
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use f-strings?

Comment: `... + str(conditionOne[0]) + ...`

Comment: "Does not allow you to use .format"?  Find a new job.

Comment: Find a new job hahaI love my job. No its this program called ignition that uses SCADA and for whatever reason formatting, like .format or f'some text {}', is just not a thing. which is gross

Comment: @MarkRansom since f-strings you don't need format at all actually

Comment: @Gameplay the point wasn't .format exactly, it was about arbitrary restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

## Edit and Answer:

I reached out to ignition personal and found out they use %d, which I have never used since the updates of python 3. I am guessing that program uses an old form of python?

Here is the code that gets it to work, if anyone else out there uses the ignition program:

```
test3 =   "switch({source}, %d, %d," % (int(conditionOne[0]),int(conditionTwo[0])) + "\"" + conditionOne[1] + "\"" + "," + "\"" + conditionTwo[1] + "\"" + ", \"Unknown\")"
```